# systemd stops writing to StandardOutput file

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

I have a simple `systemd` service on Ubuntu 20.04 where I specified the following:
`StandardOutput=file:/var/log/appname/console.log`

When I first started the service, the file got created and I saw the application's output in the file. However, the file only gets written once. When I restart the service, nothing gets written to the file even though the application is running. If I delete the file and restart the service, the file once again appears but again, it only gets written once.

Why is this happening? Should I use a different form of stdout redirection instead?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file

Comment: Are you sure nothing is getting written - rather than previous content being *overwritten* (from the start)? The [systemd-exec documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) says that `file:` causes the file to be opened "for writing at the beginning of the file, but without truncating it". Maybe try the `append:` option (introduced in v. 240 - should be available in Ubuntu 20.04, which AFAIK uses v. 245)

Answer (score 5):

I am experiencing the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04, but the content is actually being written in the begging of the file which makes it invisible to the `tail` command. This behavior is expected and described in the docs as pointed out by @steeldriver.

The problem is also discussed here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8983

**The solution** came with `version 248` released in 2021-03-30:

> `truncate:path` is similar to `file:path` above, but it truncates the
> file when opening it.

**Workaround:**

`ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/truncate --size=0 FILEPATH`

*Refs.:*

- [Systemd Release Notes](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS)
- [Systemd Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)